# Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transform, styling

I get this error message when I try to load my xml in Firefox and a blank page when I try to load in Safari and Google. Is there an error I am missing?
My styling requirements:

- Year---bold
- Title---- dark blue font weight of 900
- Director—dark green, bold
- Actors --- blue if male, pink if female
- Type---- italic and underline
- Time---- dark red, bold, underline

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="lab4_part2.xsl"?>
<streaming>
    <movies>
        <year>1985</year>
        <title>The Breakfast Club</title>
        <director>John Hughes</director>
        <actors>
            <male>Emilio Estevez</male>
            <male>Paul Gleason</male>
            <male>Anthony Micheal Hall</male>
            <male>Judd Nelson</male>
            <female>Molly Ringwald</female>
            <female>Ally Sheedy</female>
        </actors>
        <type>Comedy, Drama</type>
        <time>97</time>
    </movies>
    <movies>
        <year>1994</year>
        <title>Forrest Gump</title>
        <director>Robert Zemeckis</director>
        <actors>
            <male>Tom Hanks</male>
            <male>Mykelti Williamson</male>
            <male>Gary Sinise</male>
            <male>Haley Joel Osment</male>
            <female>Sally Field</female>
            <female>Robin Wright</female>
        </actors>
        <type>Comedy, Drama, Romance</type>
        <time>142</time>
    </movies>
</streaming>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="streaming/movies">
          <div>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="year" style="font-weight:bold;"/></p>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="title" style="color:DarkBlue; font-
weight:900;"/></p>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="director" style="color:DarkGreen; font-
weight:bold;"/></p>
            <p>Actors</p>
            <ul>
              <xsl:for-each select="streaming/movies/actors">
                <xsl:if test="name() = 'male'">
                  <li><xsl:value-of select="male" style="color:blue;"/></li>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="name() = 'female'">
                  <li><xsl:value-of select="male" style="color:pink;"/></li>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="type" style="text-decoration:underline; 
font-style:italic;"/></p>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="time" style="color:DarkRed; text-
decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;"/></p>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You've been told what the errors are, but the root cause of your problem is that you're running this stylesheet and not seeing the error messages. Generally, running XSLT in the browser isn't the best development environment, but most of the browsers do give diagnostics in the developer console and you need to become familiar with how to find them.

Comment: I've also recommend http://xsltransform.net/ as a tool for testing your XSLT, but unfortunately the service is not available at the moment...

Comment: @TimC I really think you should post a canonical answer. That service is back up now.

Answer (score 3):

All of your `xsl:value-of` statements seem to have `style` attributes on them

```
<p>
   <xsl:value-of select="year" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
</p>
```

`style` is not a valid attribute on `xsl:value-of`. You should move the `style` attribute onto the html tags you are creating in all cases. For example

```
<p style="font-weight:bold;">
   <xsl:value-of select="year" />
</p>
```

Comment: Wow yes you are so right. Dumb mistake. However, my ul of actors is still not displaying correctly.

Comment: That's a separate issue to what the question is about. But it because you are doing `<xsl:for-each select="streaming/movies/actors">`. Your context at this time is already on the `movies` node, so all you need to do is `<xsl:for-each select="actors">`

Comment: In fact, you need to do `<xsl:for-each select="actors/*" />` to get the child nodes under `actors`, and then do `<xsl:value-of select="." />` to out the actual text value of the child node.